# The unit circle provides the route of steepest ascent.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Question
[image]

I tried this problem from multivariate calculus. I could do parts $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Can someone help with part $(c)$?

How to proceed with it?

---

(a) The level curve is $z = F(x,y).$ Thus we have $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 2 \frac yz$ which is equal to $x^2 + y^2 - 2 \frac yz +1=0$.

Hence we have $x^2 + (y - 1/z)^2 = 1/z^2 -1$. Hence the level curves are circles.

(b) I have found the critical points as $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. And showed that $(0,1)$ is local maximum and $(0,-1)$ is local minimum.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: To prove you tried something include your work on parts (a) and (b). [If not your question may get closed.]

Comment: @coffeemath I have edited the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have added the parts that I have solved.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: OK now you've shown some work. You should also include your thoughts about part (c), even if you can't solve it, but at least tried something for that part of the 3-part question.

Comment: You need to re-do the level curve. A level curve of a 2 var fcn is of the form f(x,y)=c for a parameter c which varies over its possible values. You did not even have a "c" in your level curve equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part notice that the curve $F(x,y) = 0$ is not a circle
$$ F(x,y) = 0 \iff 2y = 0 \iff y = 0.$$

All over level curves are indeed circles.

---

The second part is correct.

---

For the third part recall that the gradient of a function points into the direction of steepest ascent.

In order for the path of steepest ascent to be the unit circle we require that the direction of steepest ascent at a point of the circle is tangent to circle at that point. The gradient at a point $(x,y)$ is
$$ \frac{-4xy}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}, \frac{2(x^2-y^2+1)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}$$
Now suppose that the point $(x,y)$ lies on the unit circle i.e. $x^2+y^2 = 1$
then the gradient is

$$
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{-4xy}{4},\frac{2(x^2-y^2+x^2+y^2)}{4} \right) &=  \left( \frac{-4xy}{4},\frac{2(2x^2)}{4} \right) \\
&= (-xy,x^2)
\end{align*}
.$$

Taking the dot product of the vectors $(-xy,x^2)$ and $(x,y)$ shows that these vectors are perpendicular which proves that the gradient of $F$ at $(x,y)$ is tangent to the circle. Now plug in $(x,y) = (0.8,0.6)$ which is a point of the circle to conclude.